# Выходит ошибка при нажатии кнопки KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy, kivymd

Пишу впервые на kivymd. Вышла ошибка при нажатии на кнопку и ошибка показывает на строку **spell = Spelling()**. Ошибка такая **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**. На Windows тот же код работает при нажатии но при запуске того же кода на Ubuntu 22.04 выдаёт ошибку. Я хочу взять текст из **MDTextField** ссылаясь на его id **word = self.ids.word_input.text** но выходит ошибка. Вот мой код:

main.py

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

    def press(self):

        spell = Spelling()
        spell.select_language('en_US')

        word = self.ids.word_input.text

        options = spell.suggest(word)
        x = ''
        for item in options:
            x = f'{x} {item}'

        self.ids.word_label.text = f'{x}'

class MyApp(MDApp):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = 'Speller'
    
    def build(self):
        LabelBase.register('MyFont', fn_regular='UbuntuMono-Regular.ttf')

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'

        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<MyLayout>
    id: my_widget

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 50
        spacing: 30

        MDLabel:
            id: word_label
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            text: 'Enter a word'
            font_size: 32
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            color: ('#3D405B')

        MDTextField:
            id: word_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: 1
            font_size: 32
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            hint_text: 'Spell'

        MDRaisedButton:
            size_hint: (1, 0.5)
            font_size: 32.5
            text: 'Submit'
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            on_press: root.press()
```

Объясните пожалуйста в чём проблема или может есть другое решение этой задачи. Может я не правильно ссылаюсь на Id

Comment: Понял почему не работал на Ubuntu. Я устанавливал пакет python-enchant на Windows но не установил Ubuntu и вот отсюда и не работал код. После установки пакета python-enchant всё заработало.